# Deploying C# Console App - How do I update ENV PATH via the "Publish Now" settings?

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2013, console-application

Here's the thing.  I have built a console app in .NET (C#). It works good and all is well. It's an internal tool for folks on our network, but could be used anywhere in the world (larger company). I thought I'd be able to use the simple install /deploy Wizard that comes with MS VisualStudio 2013 to generate a nice little installer. I got it set up and it works nice.

HOWEVER, once the app is installed on a target machine I want it to be usable from anywhere on the command line. Either I need to update PATH variables or have the app installed in a PATH location. The latter seems dangerous to do (putting something in SYSTEM and such), so I am wondering:

How can I get the simple Microsoft deploy wizard to update the appropriate path on the target machine while the app is being installed? I don't want to have to write some installer. I was hoping there would be some basic deployment options that let me do some custom things like this without hassle...

what am I missing? help?  thanks...

Comment: That is not possible, you'll have to write some installer.  That's not hard to do with [this add-in](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)  It lets you add a key to the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths registry key so it can be started from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I downloaded and install the extension. I added a setup project to my solution. But now I am a bit lost. Is there a tutorial on how to work with setup projects? Even trying to add the registry key with a default value (on the key on a sub-value) seems undoable, so I am needing to take a step back and look at some docs on how to use a setup project . Any suggestions on good online documentation for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up, to answer my question--- I had to create a custom install step that would update the PATH environment variable to make the computer see my new console app from any CMD window. This meant doing 2 steps:
Reading the current Path (without expanding the variables in each string) as follows:

```
        string RegKeyName = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment";
        string pathvariable = (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegKeyName).GetValue
            ("Path", "", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
```

I then split the pathvariable by semicolons and loaded it into an allpaths array variable (ignoring empty entries). Then, I iterated through allpaths in a foreach loop and rebuilt the master path, plus set a boolean to tell me if the directory I wanted to add was already in the path .  Then, once I was done that, I did the following:

```
        if (NeedtoUpdate)
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", MasterPath + MyNewPathEntry + ";", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
        }
```

That was how the custom install step worked for me.